# Design a library in Android Java

Tags: java, android, oop

I am developing a library in Android to provide basic rendering functionality to applications. My aim is to read touch inputs on GLSurfaceView (library has the ownership of this glsurfaceview) ,calculate some values and revert back to Application, which will then act according to the parameters received. It can be visualized as an interrupt raised by library to the application. 
To acheive this I have to enforce some mechanism on the client so that library can notify the events and client does what he wants with the parameters.One of the possible constucts can be using Interfaces, but since the library won't have an instance of the application activity, it cannot invoke the neccesary function.

What is the best suitable mechanism here?

Comment: Explain your requirements a bit more, please.

Comment: @Darkhogg Basically I have a GLSurfaceView and I am mapping touch input to OpenGL and calculate some variables. Consider that this process should happen in a library and library in turn wants to communicate with application so that it can act on the inputs.

Comment: The purpose of the library is to provide basic rendering functionality to applications. In addition application also get notifications based on touch events on GLSurfaceView (library has the ownership of this glsurfaceview). So I have to enforce some mechanism on the client so that library can notify the events and client does what he wants with the parameters.

Comment: Rephrase the question in a way that fits Stack Overflow, don't just add a comment – that way, the question might be reopen and kept here. I think it is actually a good question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two parts to cosider here: Input and Output.

### User Input

If the events your library needs to handle map to Android events, I would use an approach similar to that used by some of the existing libraries, which is replicating the method name and signature and return a `boolean` value indicating whther the call was already handled.

For that, create a class that acts as a *bridge* between your library and the user activity, and define the following method:

```
public boolean onKeyDown (int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    // Handle here the key event in the appropriate way
    // if the pressed key was not to be handled by your library, simply return false
    // else, handle it and return true
}
```

Then, in the caller activity, override that same method and call it appropiately

```
// We assume your bridge class is already instantiated and called `bridge`
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown (int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);

    if (bridge.onKeyDown(keyCode, event)) {
        return true;
    }

    // User code for other keys here
}
```

Extend this pattern to other methods, including `onStart` and similar if necessary. This is already in use by some Android Support utilities, such as the *Action Bar Drawer Toggle* in the `onOptionsItemSelected`. I personally use this pattern in my *Helpers* and works quite well.

### Data Output

Depending on the kind of processing you're performing, you might want to publish the results directly through the bridge class methods or by using listeners.

If computations are fast and needed frequently but not *always*, it might be beneficial to use a `get` method:

```
public Object getResult () {
    // Use an appropriate return type and method name
}
```

However, if the results are performed in a separate thread because they are slow or they will be used only once, at the time they are processed, it might be better to use a `Callbacks` type of interface, similar to that found in the *Loaders* framework.

Inside of your bridge class, define an interface like this:

```
public class Bridge {

    interface Callbacks {
        void onSomeResultComputed (Object result);
        void onSomeOtherResultComputed (Object result);
        // etc.
    }

    // Other methods and fields
}
```

Then make the client register this callbacks using either an specific method for it or using an `onCreate` that follows the pattern described above. Client code would look like this

```
public class SomeActivity implements Bridge.Callbacks {

   [...]

   @Override
   protected void onCreate () {
       super.onCreate();
       bridge.onCreate(this);
   }

   [...]

   @Override
   public void onSomeResultComputed (Object result) {
       // Handle the result here
   }

   @Override
   public void onSomeOtherResultComputed (Object result) {
       // Handle the result here
   }
}
```

Again, Google already uses this pattern in some Android utilities such as *Loaders* and in some of the Google Play Services classes, and it works quite well.

Remember in the case of listener to perform costly computatons in parallel threads (possibli using `AsyncTask`) and to always call the `Callbacks` method again in the main thread.

Comment: In order to invoke the onSomeResultComputed() method on client side do we use the object passed in bridge.onCreate(this); method ? 
The idea of bridge class is fantastic.

Comment: Yes, the `this` there is just an object implementing the `Callbacks` interface, it just happens to be implemented by the Activity itself (and thus `this` is passed).